# How do I deal with a lot of fields of different products in view modes of product display?

Tags: 7, entities, commerce

Scenario is this: Let's say I have one product display for car parts and every car part have different attributes (or not necessarily attributes but some fields used for faceted search for example), so every view mode of my product display would end up full of different fields of all kind of products. It potentially can be A LOT of stuff. I don't think that creating many product displays ONLY to overcome this problem, would be a good idea if what I really need is only one. What I would be able to do with this mess of fields?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to reduce the complexity of the product list. You do not have to display a field to filter on it. You can simplify the display and expose filters for the user.

Comment: But I want to display those fields to user :) .